# Assigning output of query value to string

Tags: c, database, postgresql

I am trying to assign a string to the output of query value. I am using PostgreSQL to execute commands and my code looks following:

```
int finding_string(int id_subject){
char STRING[255];
PGconn *conn;
PGresult *res;

conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=username host=host_address user=username password=password");

char o[255];
sprintf(o, "SELECT credits FROM subject WHERE id_subject = %d;", id_subject);
printf("%s\n", o);
res = PQexec(conn, o);

sprintf(STRING, "%s", PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0));
printf("%s \n", STRING);
```

So the focus is on line `sprintf(p, "SELECT average_grade FROM student WHERE student_code = %d;", student_code);` where I get the output of query. This command works well, but when I try to use `sprintf(STRING, "%s", PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0));` the program crashes in that line and does not print the string.
Can anyone tell me what might be the issue and offer a solution so that I could assign the output of query to a string?
Any help is really appreciated as I'm starting to lose hope..

Comment: I dont know why the title is as it is.. I changed it but it seems like it stayed the same :(

Comment: Try with `snprintf`, and check it's return value

Comment: Did `PQconnectdb` work? Did `PQexec` work? Did `PQgetvalue` work? The answer to that last question is almost certainly, "Nope, it returned NULL, and that caused `sprintf` to crash." The code needs to check what each function returned, and handle the error if an error occurs.

Comment: @user3386109 PQconnectDB and PQexec both worked, but PQgetvalue does not appear to be working. But the query command itself is correct, so I cant understand why PQgetvalue does not appear to be working..

Comment: You should add the exact error message and the stack trace to the question. Perhaps the result exceeds 254 characters and you have a buffer overrun.